# Wp-CLI not working with WordPress installed with composer

Tags: directory, wp-cli, composer

I've installed a version of Wordpress using composer, and modified the default folders for the content (/wp-content) and the core (/wp).

My wp-config.php gets its DB_NAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD from environment variables defined in the .htaccess file.

I am able to connect to my wordpress instance using my browser, so the connection information in there is fine.

I have not managed to get wp-cli to run on this instance. wp-cli --debug outputs:

```
Debug (bootstrap): No readable global config found (0.014s)
Debug (bootstrap): No project config found (0.016s)
Debug (bootstrap): No package autoload found to load. (0.261s)
Debug (bootstrap): ABSPATH defined: /path/to/core/ (0.272s)
Debug (bootstrap): Begin WordPress load (0.288s)
Debug (bootstrap): wp-config.php path: /path/to/wp-config.php (0.292s)
Error: Error establishing a database connection
```

(I've double checked these paths and they are correct)

I keep getting that same error.
I've tried installing a clean instance using composer, but this time :

- without any plugin
- without any theme
- by defining the DB_NAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD directly in the wp-config.php file rather than getting those from env. variables.
- but I kept the custom folder structure /wp for the core and /wp-content for the content

Still the same error...
Am I missing something ?
Is it the custom folder structure that wp-cli doesn't like ?

```
Executing wp-cli --info outputs this :
PHP binary: /usr/bin/php
PHP version:    5.5.36
php.ini used:
WP-CLI root dir:    phar://wp-cli.phar
WP-CLI packages dir:
WP-CLI global config:
WP-CLI project config:
WP-CLI version: 0.24.1
```

I'm on Max OS X El Capitan.

Thanks a lot for your help,

Julien

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling WP-CLI from the parent directory you need to tell it where core is using `--path`

```
$ wp --path=path/to/core
```

Some more details here: http://wp-cli.org/config/

You can set also set this with a config file `wp-cli.yml` that contains

```
path: path/to/core
```

Details: http://wp-cli.org/config/#config-files

Comment: Hey, thanks kraftner ! I've tried `wp --path htdocs/wp` when I execute if from above `htdocs` but it still doesn't work... It finds the correct path to my w^-config.php file, so I really dont't get why it doesn't work. Any chance it could be something like the version of PHP or the way the connection to MySQL is supposed to work ?

Comment: Ahhhh... Found : I installed wp-cli outside of my VM, so the `localhost` it finds in my `wp-config.php`doesn't quite work :)

Comment: :) Good you resolved it. Maybe you want to add that as an answer too and accept it. I guess this is a pretty common mistake to make so other would profit from this.